# How to solve the problem that pandoc fails to convert latex formulas to docx

Tags: latex, pandoc, mathjax, tex

I want to convert the following latex formula into a formula in docx. The latex formula can be used normally on both mathtype and mathjaxjs.

```
$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}} {(m + 2)x = 1}\\ {3x - (m - 3){y^{\left| m \right| - 2}} + 4 = 0} \end{array}} \right.$
```

You can test latex to docx on the pandoc-try[https://pandoc.org/try/] website
When I use pandoc to convert, the following warning message appears:

```
Could not convert TeX math \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}} {(m + 2)x = 1}\\ {3x - (m - 3){y^{\left| m \right| - 2}} + 4 = 0} \end{array}} \right., rendering as TeX: t\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}} {(m + 2)x = ^ unexpected "*" expecting white space, letter, "|" or "}"
```

I want the latex above to be converted to docx normally!!
How can I solve this problem? thanks！！！

Comment: This has nothing to do with the $ identifier. I tested that pandoc does not support the writing method ```{*{20}{l}```. I searched for relevant information and found that it seems to be the writing method used to align formulas in latex.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed this is a feature not yet supported by pandoc, please check out this [issues_229](https://github.com/jgm/texmath/issues/229)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!